# Which is the best way to analyse gradle project sonar analysis - gradle task or SonarScanner and why

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, sonarscanner

Which is the best way to analyse sonar on a gradle project - gradle task "sonarqube" or SonarScanner and why.?

Comment: Gradle task from sonar gradle plugin  runs sonar scanner underneath 

Comment: But sonarqube task first build the project and then run the scanner. What if gradle build is already done.
However, SonarScanner does not run the build

Comment: Gradle will handle this, trust it